# Extracting multiline commit log in SVN pre commit hook

Tags: batch-file, svn, pre-commit-hook

I was trying to get the full commit comment in pre commithook. Following is my code,

```
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2 
SET comment
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN%') do (SET comment=%comment%%%g)
```

but I am only able to get the last line of the log. Is there any way i can get the full log (multiline)?

Comment: Thank you Dialecticus for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have a delayed expansion problem.  It is one of those quirky things with how batch files expand variables before the line of code is executed.  So you have two options to work around this issue.

Enable delayed expansion and use exclamation points to reference your variables.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN%') do (SET comment=!comment!%%g)
```

Use a little trickery with the `CALL` command. YOu double the percent symbols and use the CALL command which gives you two phases of variable expansion.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN%') do (CALL SET comment=%%comment%%%%g)
```